# filter results returned by django-reversion

Tags: python, django, django-reversion

Just started using [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) with the Polls application from the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/). To get this working, all I did was to create `mysite/polls/admin.py` with the following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Poll
import reversion
#admin.site.register(Poll)
class PollAdmin(reversion.VersionAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

In other words, I have done only the Admin Integration. To the Poll model, I added a field called `approved`.

`one_object = Poll.objects.all()[1]`
`version_list = reversion.get_unique_for_object(one_object)`

The `version_list` above contains all the versions of `one_object`. I only want to get all the versions that have `approved==True`. I then want the results to a view so that only the approved polls can be displayed. How can I filter this?

Answer (score 0):

Each version object has a `field_dict` attribute containing the values of the object's fields at that version. So you can filter the list as follows:

```
filtered_versions = [v for v in version_list if v.field_dict["approved"] ==  True]
```